# Usando ajax para executar um codigo em php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Olá, estou com um problema de como usar o ajax para executar um código em php, estou horas tentando achar o problema, mas não consigo.

Código js

```
$.ajax({                        
    url: 'deletarOrgs.php',
    data: {
       id: $id
    },
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(){
        alert("sucess");
    },
    error: function(){
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

Código php

```
<?php 
    include 'class/OrgaosColabDAO.php';    
    $DAO = new OrgaosColabDAO();
    $DAO->deletarOC($_POST['id']);    
?>
```

Testei o php separadamente, ele funciona direito. Quando executo o js, o ajax executa a função de error.

Desde já, agradeço.

Edit:

O proposito do ajax é deletar um objeto de meu banco, para controlar quando eu quero deleta-lo, eu clico em um botão que abre um modal (estou usando o modal do bootstrap 3) aonde tem 2 botões, sim ou não. O ajax executa quando clico no botão Sim.
O estranho é quando eu não uso o modal, executando o ajax quando eu clico no primeiro botão, o ajax funciona do jeito certo.

```
$('#deletar-sim').click(function (){                    
    $.ajax({                        
        url: 'deletarOrgs.php',
            data: {
                id: $id
            },
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(){
                alert("a");
            },
            error: function (request, status, error){
                alert(request.responseText);
            }
    });
});
```

Comment: Vou dar meu palpite.
Tente retirar o "$" da parte do JavaScript.

Comment: troca a função `error` por `error: function (request, status, error){alert(request.responseText);}` executa mais uma vez e posta o resultado para dar mais uma pista da possível causa disso aí féra.

Comment: Em $.ajax() ? Retirar ele fez que o código inteiro do JavaScript não executasse.

Comment: Tenta colocar um retorno boolean(true), no PHP, acredito que como nada é retornado o Ajax não identifica que a operação foi bem sucedida.

Comment: A janela de alerta some muito rápido, então eu não consegui ler. Eu editei o post com mais informações.

Comment: De onde vem o valor de `$id`?